# Syncing folders across machines in Linux

Tags: linux, sync

My question is similar to followings, but I don't find they match exactly what I am looking for. So I am here trying to get some experience of yours.

[How to synchronize the home folder between multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/31512/how-to-synchronize-the-home-folder-between-multiple-computers)

[Sync $HOME across linux machines](https://superuser.com/questions/567194/sync-home-across-linux-machines)

I want to achieve following:

1. syncing certain folders among multiple machines, say 3 but might get increased,
2. customizable target folders, much better with negation and other complex rules,
3. since I might want to sync between laptops, it would be nice if it can be integrated into OS to sync automatically when connected to network,
4. a central server is preferred. It would be nice to have scheduled backup archives as well,
5. other customizable easy settings, like how to handle symlink etc,
6. conflict resolution can be arbitrary, but needs to be automatic,
7. It would be nice if things work in a subscriber-publisher pattern,
8. things need to work 100% automatically.

I am thinking of `rsync` at the beginning but after checking different answers, I noticed other options. But it's too much to try out all of them. Any existing tool already that can do the job? One thing to note that I do not what any external services(amazon, dropbox, etc), but something local that I can admin.

Comment: I can recommend `rsync` + a `cron` job.

Comment: @DjDac this was my original plan, but scheduled task can't achieve syncing based on notification. I am probably looking for something more complicated.

Comment: We are not going to recommend you a piece of software to do all the things you listed. This site is for fixing problems with software, not recommending it.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 no, this site is to answer problems from admins. this is a well valid question that certain admins would like to do and some might have experience with it. just to the right of my question, i see a list of variant questions of the same type, i see no reason why mine should be excluded and disregarded.

Comment: you're probably looking for syncthing.

Comment: @Sirex wonderful. checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) in a previous job. It was used to keep synced a directory of documents between all employees (we were 3 or 4 at a time)

I never used it myself, but I saw multiple times the name [Lsyncd](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/lsyncd-live-file-syncronization-linux/) which looks like a rsync daemon which pushes real time the modifications.

Comment: Unison would work for HuStmpHrrr since he'd prefer a centralized server, and Unison works as a bi-directionnal sync between two hosts : he would run a Unison daemon per "synced hosts". That would not handle archived backup though, and it's not exactly trivial to configure and maintain.

Comment: @zerodeux archive is ok. i can just run a cron job to zip or git it.